# Selecting rows in attribute table by date (QGIS)

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-3

I want to select rows in an attribute table by date using PYQGIS.

The column is called “Date.” This is my script:

```
import qgis.utils
from qgis.utils import iface

layer = iface.activeLayer()
layer.selectByExpression('"Date"=\'2021-09-06 20:36:59\'')
```

The script runs, does not throw an error, and also does not select the desired row.
To make sure I wasn’t doing something wrong with function inputs, I tried this on different columns in the same attribute table:

```
layer.selectByExpression('"Elevation"=\'SG-3\'') 
layer.selectByExpression('"Location"=\'North of B1\'')
layer.selectByExpression('"Maximum Dry Density"=\'138\'')
```

All of these produced the desired outcome – the rows were selected.

More details in case relevant: Attribute table values were all input using the Mergin Maps field app, then synced to the project using Mergin's plugin. The Date column is the only input that is auto-filled in the app. All other inputs are manual.

I have looked in the PYQGIS Developer Cookbook and various posts here on StackExchange and haven't found a solution. Any advice welcome.

Comment: Can you check the type of Date column (Layer rightClick > Properties... > Fields). It is String, Date or Datetime?

Comment: The field type is Datetime.

Comment: It's Year-Month-Day (specifically yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss).

Comment: The date is displayed exactly as it is in my code above: 2021-09-06 20:36:59

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In your use case, QGIS considers it as a string. You need to convert it to datetime format.

Use this:

```
expression = "Date = to_datetime('2021-09-06 20:36:59', 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss')"
layer.selectByExpression(expression)
```

If you want to be able to select rows by just `yyyy-MM-dd`, since the type of Date is `DateTime`, you need to convert into `Date` using `to_date`.

```
expression = "to_date(Date) = to_date('2021-09-06', 'yyyy-MM-dd')"
```